# Как записать в файл сумму двух переменных?

Tags: java

Есть программа, но запись в файл суммы не производится. В чем ошибка?

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws java.io.IOException{
    File myfile =new File("text.txt");


    FileReader reader = new FileReader(myfile);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(reader);
 int str = scan.nextInt();
 int str2 = scan.nextInt();
 int sum = str+str2;
    reader.close();


    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.println(str2);
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(myfile);
    writer.write(sum);

    writer.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {
    File myfile = new File("text.txt");

    FileReader reader = new FileReader(myfile);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(reader);
    int str = scan.nextInt();
    int str2 = scan.nextInt();

    int sum = str + str2;
    reader.close();

    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.println(str2);
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(myfile);
    writer.write(String.valueOf(sum));

    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: Не создается файл. Выдается такая ошибка:Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: text.txt (Не удается найти указанный файл)
 at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
 at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
 at java.base/java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:75)

Comment: File myfile = new File("text.txt"); - эта строчка говорит о том, что ваши цифры, которые вы хотите сложить, вы будете читать из файла с указанным именем. данный файл должен иметь такое имя и находится в корневом каталоге проекта. ошибка FileNotFoundException говороит о том, что файла с таким именем в корне проекта нет

Comment: Разве этот метод самостоятельно не создает файл?

Comment: у вас есть строка кода  int sum = str + str2; откуда по вашему должны появиться цифры для суммирования?